# Where can I get the faceconn.php file?

Tags: php, facebook

Ijust visited the http://faceconn.com/facebook-stream-publish-php site and tried a sample code. 
I have downloaded the php sdk too but can't find the 'faceconn/faceconn.php' file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
       <title>Facebook Stream Publish PHP example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
           require_once 'facebook.php';
           require_once 'faceconn/faceconn.php';
           UseGraphAPI();

           $publish = new StreamPublish();
           $publish->SetName("Story Name");
           $publish->SetNameUrl("http://faceconn.com");
           $publish->SetCaption("{*actor*} publish this story:");
           $publish->SetDescription("This is a description of the story");
           $publish->SetOnPublishJavaScript("alert('Published')");
           $publish->SetMedia(new ImageMedia("http://faceconn.com/img/cat.png", "http://faceconn.com"));
           $publish->AddPropery(new Property("Product Name", "Faceconn Toolkit"));
           $publish->AddActionLink(new ActionLink("Faceconn", "http://faceconn.com"));
           $publish->Render();
       ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where can I get this file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the website, the toolkit is licensed: http://faceconn.com/licensing-facebook-connect